# Removing jQuery from a document (garbage collection)

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, performance-testing

I'd like to know if it's possible to remove executed JS code from a document. Let's say I've loaded jQuery, but I no longer need it, is it viable to simply run `delete window.$` and such or is there a *proper* way to do this?

**Why would I want to do this?**

I'm running some performance tests, at the moment they're inside an `<iframe>` to allow a clean slate for each suite, but this isn't very feasible as some of the devices I'm testing don't support `<iframes>` (yep, magic).

So what I'd like to do is essentially load some library based code within a container of some sort, test it and then clear it ready for garbage collection, if this is at all possible within the current state of JS.

Note: I've used jQuery as an example since it's a big library with its 100% coverage and all.

Comment: are you planning to remove the complete js library which you have loaded in iframe ?

Comment: Yep, the whole thing. It's so that when I test another library, jQuery's code isn't left in memory potentially affecting the performance of other tests.

Comment: Is it feasible to load a new window for each test?

Comment: Nope, these devices don't support windows; that's why I was using iframes, til I worked out that they didn't support them.

Comment: ok their could be a work around, if it is using some server side script then you could toggle the JS lib by refreshing iFrame and passing the key or session value as key to which JS should be loaded ?